# Is apprenticeship/reading the only way to learn experimental design? Are there books/papers about the theory of designing a sound experiment?

Tags: research-process, experiment-design, project-design

I am slogging away at grad school and I have a nagging feeling I can be more efficient. I feel like a person who cannot see more than a foot in front of them so I hit a lot of walls. My planning and experiment design could use a lot of work but interacting with my PI only gets me but so far. I am in a new lab so I do not have senior students to consult with either. Are there any good written resources about how to design experiments in a general sense?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I am in biological sciences, but if the comments/answers could be broadened to include all STEM it would be much appreciated.

**2nd Update**

When I refer to experimental design I am referring to something broader than setting up controls or statistical power. I am doing a poor job of alluding to something broader and more general. What is a good research question and the transition from a neat idea to a framework of experiment that addresses such a question.

To use a chess analogy, I am learning tactical play, forks, skewers, pins etc.... I am getting better at moving pieces, but what is preventing me from taking the next step is the absence of a strategy  How do I string these tactics together to win? I come up with cool ideas but I cannot grasp molding and shaping that idea into a series of experiments that tell a short narrative.

I would like to know different styles of this process and strengths and weaknesses of both. I am not getting very far with my local dialogue options so I was hoping people may write about this subject. Hopefully that clarifies my question.

Comment: What field is this?

Comment: @Buffy I updated my post.

Comment: Still need more information. Is it a statistical study (Applied Statistics books cover that) or a purely biological or pharmacological study of some sort?

Comment: you would probably get more traction from this question on crossvalidated, e.g. stats.stackexchange.com. I can guess that as a biologist, you are probably going to care about statistical designs which minimize cost and models that account for psuedo-replication.

Comment: Two relevant questions on Crossvalidated: [Recommended books on experiment design?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1815), and [References for how to plan a study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1352). I didn't see it mentioned in the questions I linked, but David Glass's [Experimental Design for Biologists](https://www.amazon.com/Experimental-Design-Biologists-Second-David/dp/1621820416) appears to be a well regarded textbook, and suitable too.

Comment: @JWH2006 I am looking for steps one ponders prior to getting to nitty gritty of how many samples to run etc...

Comment: @Anyon Thanks for the links. I will check these out.

Comment: @Buffy Updated again.